# Как ведёт себя этот код?

Tags: c

Input:

```
int main (void){
  int x = 10, z = 20;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", x++, x++, x++);
  printf("%d %d %d", ++z, ++z, ++z);
}
```

Output:

```
12 11 10
23 23 23
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Как написано — так и ведет... Компилятор имеет полное право скомпилировать и так, и эдак...

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему при ++z в принт возвращается сразу выполненное до конца выражение, а при x++ возвращается в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

++z увеличивает значение z, а затем возвращает z

x++ возвращает значение x, а затем увеличивает, именно по этой причине код ведет себя подобным образом

Как именно ведет себя код:

Создается функция, задаются переменные, идет вывод х и z, но x у вас изначально вернул значение, а потом увеличил, и так 3 раза, а z увеличил на 3, а потом вернул все 3 числа.

++z: загрузить z из памяти, увеличить, использовать, сохранить обратно в память.

x++: загрузка x из памяти, использование, увеличение, сохранение в памяти.

Очень влияет предоставили ли  Вы параметр после извлечения, после использования или после хранения

Comment: И всё же непонятно, почему `12 11 10`, наверное `print` перебирает аргументы с конца к началу, поэтому.

Comment: Потому что UB. Читайте на Википедии подробнее что это такое.